# When creating a global object in JavaScript why do I need to specify the this keyword

Tags: javascript

Say I'm trying to create a global variable x if it doesn't already exist:

```
x = x || {};            //This fails. x is not defined
this.x = this.x || {};  //But this works
```

I'm running this in Firebug and was surprised that the 1st line failed. I expected x to be attached to the global window object, but it didn't work unless I specified the `this`.

I'm hoping to improve my understanding of the language. Can someone explain to me why this is?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Because `x` is not declared. It works if you have: `var x;` and then `x = x || {}`. When you're using `this` you don't have that problem because you're accessing to `x` as *property* (of the global object) not as *variable*.

Comment: `this.x` works because you are effectively adding an reference to 'x' into the 'window'. In a global scope, `this` refers to `window`

Answer (score 2):

- If you try and use an undeclared variable a part of an expression, you'll get a `ReferenceError` thrown.
- If you try and assign an undeclared variable, the variable will be declared as an implicit global. Implicit globals are bad.

```
x = x || {};  
    ^  its this x that breaks it.
```

To correctly check whether a variable is declared, you should use the `typeof variable === "undefined"` check.

Undefined attributes however (in your second example, `x` is an attribute on `this`), hold the value `undefined` by default.